# Data type for storing large numbers

Tags: c++, gcc, types, largenumber

I have a program which needs to store several numbers. The largest one can be of the order 10^15. How should I go about storing the number.

I'm using Gcc 4.3.2 compiler.

Comment: What kind of numbers – integers, approximate reals, exact fractions...?

Answer (score 7):

`long long` would fit 10^15 as it is 64 bits.

To see the limit values of all the data types you could use the `<limits>` header.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>    

int main() {
    //print maximum of various types
    std::cout << "Maximum values :\n";
    std::cout << "Short : " << std::numeric_limits<short>::max() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int : " << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Long : " << std::numeric_limits<long>::max() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Long Long: " << std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Float : " << std::numeric_limits<float>::max() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Double : " << std::numeric_limits<double>::max() << std::endl;

    //print minimum of various types
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Minimum Values: \n";
    std::cout << "Short : " << std::numeric_limits<short>::min() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Int : " << std::numeric_limits<int>::min() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Long : " << std::numeric_limits<long>::min() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Long Long: " << std::numeric_limits<long long>::min() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Float : " << std::numeric_limits<float>::min() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Double : " << std::numeric_limits<double>::min() << std::endl;
}
```

Which outputs (on my machine):

```
Maximum values :
Short : 32767
Int : 2147483647
Long : 2147483647
Long Long: 9223372036854775807
Float : 3.40282e+038
Double : 1.79769e+308

Minimum Values: 
Short : -32768
Int : -2147483648
Long : -2147483648
Long Long: -9223372036854775808
Float : 1.17549e-038
Double : 2.22507e-308
```

Comment: To be a more explicit, 2^64 ~ 10^19. You have roughly log(2^64) / log(10) = 19 digits in a `long long`.

Comment: @Rapptz IS long long supported by GCC+ 4.3.2 compiler?